# Is there a good way to use private variables and methods in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've noticed that I could use private variables like this:

```
var Hello = React.createClass(new (function(){

    var name;

    this.getInitialState = function() {
        name = "Sir " + this.props.name;
        return null;
    };

    this.render = function() {
        return <div>Hello {name}</div>;
    };
})());

React.render(<Hello name="World" />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Why I should not be doing this?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 7):

Private vars are perfect when you need local (private) state information for a component that does NOT change or relate to rendering directly. Keep in mind, most things do change rendering so I have found that I use private vars rarely.

Also, keep in mind when you add a variable to the class the way you did, its a singleton so it will be shared with all instances of that component. This can lead to issues if truly want something private for each instance -- if thats what you want, then you need to declare it in one of the lifecycle methods for the component perhaps like this

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.name = 'hello';
},
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using es7, you can define class properties as a private variables like this:

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  name = 'Jack';
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.name}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Hello;
```

Be sure to use [babel](http://babeljs.io/) to compile your code with [stage 0](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/experimental/#stage-0)

Comment: I am using Babel since yesterday, but isn't "name" public?

Comment: @melanke Babel compile it to `this.name`, [compile online](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=class%20Hello%20extends%20React.Component%20%7B%0A%20%20name%20%3D%20'Jack'%3B%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7Bthis.name%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Aexport%20default%20Hello%3B), so you are right, it's a public variable

Comment: This is still going to be public. TypeScript adds accessors, so you can do `private name: string = "Jack";` but AFAIK, that's not supported by ES7 in any way.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's anything wrong with it. The syntax is a bit funky, but it's a smart trick.

I would question the need for a truly private variable. I can only think of two reasons why someone might want one, but both can be debunked.

1) You make a library to be consumed by others... If someone is poking around inside your library code where they're not supposed to be, their either breaking their own experience or working around bugs they have found in your code. Either way, no harm to you or others. Worse case, they break their own app. Private variables left a really bad taste in my mouth coming from Flex. JavaScript's openness is a breath of fresh air IMO.

2) You want to hide private data inside your app... With modern browsers, anything in JavaScript can be inspected and modified at run time. It's impossible to hide data from users in JavaScript. You can only make things hard to find.

I know this alternative isn't truly private, but the usage is the same. Since I'm not a big fan of fighting hard to make things private, I'll include it anyway. ;g)

```js
var Hello = React.createClass({

    name: null,

    getInitialState: function() {
        this.name = "Sir " + this.props.name;
        return null;
    },

    render: function() {
        return <div>Hello {this.name}</div>;
    };
});

React.render(<Hello name="World" />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: Well, I am a big fan of private variables, because someone of my team may try to use the variable by mistake and take hours to find out that it was not suppose to be used. Sometimes if it is used will make the software slower or a imperceptible bug. In other languages like Java or C# is very common to use private variables, actually I use more private variables than public variables.

Comment: I understand. I write lots of Java. However it's just not the way things are typically done in JS. Most times I don't care about the inner workings of a library. However in the rare case that I do care, I'm trying to mock a poorly designed library and the private variables / anon functions prevent me from writing a good unit test or just working around a bug... IMO, it's akin to using "final" methods in Java (which in most frameworks are unmockable).... If you feel you need private data to protect yourself from devs, I'd look at your devs or your library, not the coding principles.